# How do I add a row to an association table in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the below tables and I want to add a row to the association table, how do I do that? I'm trying to have it so when a user fills out the shows form and submits it, it adds a row to the association table that has both the artist id and the venue id.

I tried doing the bellow but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
@app.route('/shows/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_show_submission():
  try:
    venue_id = request.form.get('venue_id')
    artist_id = request.form.get('artist_id')
    start_time = request.form.get('start_time')

    venue = Venue.query.filter_by(id = venue_id).all()
    artist = Artist.query.filter_by(id = artist_id).all()

    if venue and artist:
        show = shows(venue_id = venue_id, artist_id=artist_id, start_time=start_time)
        db.session.add(show)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Show was successfully listed!')
```

Tables:

```
    shows = db.Table ('shows',
    db. Column('show_id', db.Integer, primary_key= True),
    db.Column('venue_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Venue.id'), nullable = False ),
    db.Column('artist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Artist.id'), nullable = False ),
    db.Column('start_time', db.String(), nullable = False)
    )
    
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Venue'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    upcoming_shows=db.Column(db.String(120))
    upcoing_shows_count=db.Column(db.Integer)
    genres = db.relationship('Genres', backref ='venue')

    # TODO: implement any missing fields, as a database migration using Flask-Migrate

class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Artist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    website = db.Column(db.String(120))
    upcoming_shows=db.Column(db.String(120))
    upcoing_shows_count=db.Column(db.Integer)
    genres = db.relationship('Genres', backref ='artist')
```

Comment: If you want to store additional information about a Show (other than just the associated Artist and Venue) then you'll want to make Show an [association *object*](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) instead of just a plain association *table*.

Comment: No, but how do I store the associated artist and venue?

Comment: The id values of the associated Artist and Venue are stored in the table that backs the Show object.

Comment: how do I store them in the association table? for example artist 6 with venue 3