# What's the difference between an association table and a regular table?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't think I fully understand association tables. I know how to work with normal tables i.e add rows and what not but I don't understand how to work with an association table.

why would I use the below

```
    student_identifier = db.Table('student_identifier',
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.class_id')),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.user_id'))
)
```

Vs

```
class studentIdent(db.model):
  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.class_id')),
  db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('students.user_id'))
```

Comment: Generally you never use the association table directly in your code, so there's no value in creaing a model class.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - see comments to related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65512225/2144390)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the question, you would not bother creating a `class` for the association table if it only contains the foreign keys linking the two tables in the many-to-many relationship. In that case your first example – an *association **table*** – would be sufficient.

However, if you want to store additional information about the nature of the link between the two tables then you will want to create an [*association **object***](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) so you can manipulate those additional attributes:

```py
class StudentIdent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "student_identifier"
    course_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        primary_key=True, 
        autoincrement=False,
        db.ForeignKey('courses.course_id')
    )
    user_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, 
        primary_key=True, 
        autoincrement=False,
        db.ForeignKey('students.user_id')
    )
    enrolment_type = db.Column(db.String(20))
    # reason for student taking this course
    #   e.g., "core course", "elective", "audit"
```

and then you could create the link between a given student and a particular course by creating a new instance of the association object:

```py
thing = StudentIdent(course_id=3, user_id=6, enrolment_type="elective")
```

Note: This is just a basic linkage. You can get more sophisticated by explicitly declaring a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) between the ORM objects.

Comment: Thank you but I guess my question is why not just always create a class? it seems more versatile, is there a benefit to it?

Comment: One benefit of creating a class when it is not strictly necessary (at the moment) would be for future-proofing. You may have a many-to-many relationship that doesn't *currently* need to have extra attributes associated with it, but your experience and professional judgment tells you that it *might* require such additional attributes later on. In that case you could build the model using a class because it wouldn't really hurt anything and it would make it easier to expand the model later on.